# Yandex Maps Изменение координат метки при смене координат

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет!
Карта уже реализована - 3 плашки, при нажатии на которые меняется адрес. Осталось дело за малым - никак не удаётся показать метку при смене координат. То есть на первом адресе она есть, но дальше не получается... Понимаю, что надо обновить значение *myMap*, но как это сделать в данном случае?

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
destinations = {
    'г.Кировск': [59.889823064234115, 30.991006000000013],
    'г. Отрадное': [59.761984064403514, 30.77406249999994],
    'пгт. Мга': [59.75674056442115, 31.060580499999993]
},

myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: destinations['г.Кировск'],
    zoom: 16
}),

myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
    hintContent: 'Кировск',
}, {
    // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    // Своё изображение иконки метки.
    iconImageHref: '/wp/wp-content/themes/smile32/image/icon/place.svg',
    // Размеры метки.
    iconImageSize: [40, 40],
});

function clickGoto() {
    // город
    var city = $(this).find('.title__cont');
    var pos = city.text();
    // переходим по координатам
    myMap.panTo(destinations[pos], {
        flying: 1
    });
    return false;
}

// навешиваем обработчики
var col = document.getElementsByClassName('box__cont');
for (var i = 0, n = col.length; i < n; ++i) {
    col[i].onclick = clickGoto;
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нашёл хитрую лазейку, а именно:

```
function clickGoto() {
    // город
    var city = $(this).find('.title__cont');
    var pos = city.text();
    var long = $(this).attr('data-long');
    var width = $(this).attr('data-width');
    // переходим по координатам
    myMap.panTo(destinations[pos], {
        flying: 1
    });
    myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates([long, width]);
    return false;
}
```

Т. е. подставил data-атрибуты с координатами и считал их в js) Всё гениальное просто!